# Finding a performance bottleneck between Mule 4.3 and ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, project-reactor, mule4, appdynamics

We have been experiencing severely high response times between all of our Mule 4.3 instances that communicate with ActiveMQ, because of these issues our team has installed an APM (AppDynamics) agent in our Mule JVM's to debug the issue at hand.

The most interesting thing that I came out of our APM is the following call graph visible below (The most time per call is also spend in interacting with ActiveMQ):

```
Call graph from /api/transaction_1
On tier: TIER-01
On node: node-001.net
Start time: 10/04/21 4:24:39 PM

java.lang.Thread:run:748 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
 reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask:call:27 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
  reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask:call:50 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
   reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar:run:178 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber:onNext:345 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
     reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
      reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
       reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber:onNext:180 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber:onNext:76 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
         reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
          reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner:onNext:974 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
           reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain:tryEmit:532 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
            reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner:onNext:242 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
             reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber:onNext:213 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
              reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
               reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                 reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber:onNext:345 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                  reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                   reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                    reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                     reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                      reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                       reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                        reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                         reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber:onNext:180 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                          reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                           reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                            reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                             reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                              reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                               reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                                reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                                 reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:482 (method time = 1884 ms, total time = 28049 ms)
                                  reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink:next:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 0 ms)
                                  reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink:next:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                   reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:next:718 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                    reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:drain:793 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                     reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                      reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                       reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                        reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                         reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                          reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                           reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber:onNext:121 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                            reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                             reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                              reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                               reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                 reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:482 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                  reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink:next:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                   reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:next:718 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                    reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:drain:793 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                     reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                      reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                       reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                        reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                         reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                          reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                           reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber:onNext:121 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                            reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                             reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                              reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                               reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                 reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber:onNext:180 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                  reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                   reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                    reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                     reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                      reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                       reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                        reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                         reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber:onNext:180 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                          reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                           reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                            reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                             reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                              reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                               reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                 reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber:onNext:180 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                  reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                   reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                    reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                     reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                      reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                       reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber:onNext:846 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                        reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber:onNext:213 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                         reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                          reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber:onNext:130 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                           reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink:next:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                            reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:next:718 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                             reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:drain:793 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                              reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                               reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner:onNext:242 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                 reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber:onNext:114 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                  reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner:onNext:242 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                   reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                    reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber:onNext:121 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                     reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                      reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                       reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                        reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                         reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                          reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                           reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber:onNext:127 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                            reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:496 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                             reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:287 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                              reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:482 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                               Spring Bean - _mulePolicyManager:lambda$static$0:84 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                                reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink:next:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                                 reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:next:718 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                                  reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:drain:793 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                                   reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                                    reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:496 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                                     reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber:onNext:482 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26165 ms)
                                                                                                                      net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor:getStageAsync:178 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                       net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor:callAsync:346 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                        net.jodah.failsafe.AsyncExecution:executeAsync:174 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                         net.jodah.failsafe.Functions:lambda$makeAsync$2:79 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                          net.jodah.failsafe.Functions:lambda$null$1:69 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                           net.jodah.failsafe.internal.executor.RetryPolicyExecutor:lambda$supplyAsync$1:133 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                            net.jodah.failsafe.internal.executor.RetryPolicyExecutor$1:call:101 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                             net.jodah.failsafe.Functions:lambda$promiseOfStage$8:193 (method time = 26148 ms, total time = 26148 ms)
                                                                                                                              JMS(28030ms): acme.corp.error.topic
                                                                                                                      reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink:next:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                       reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:next:718 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                        reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink:drain:793 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                         reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber:onNext:103 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                          reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                           reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber:onNext:204 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                            reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner:onNext:242 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                             reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber:onNext:114 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                              reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner:onNext:242 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                               reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnConditionalSubscriber:onNext:704 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                                reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnConditionalSubscriber:trySchedule:759 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                                 reactor.core.scheduler.ExecutorServiceWorker:schedule:43 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                                  reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers:workerSchedule:904 (method time = 17 ms, total time = 17 ms)
                                                                                                                                   undefined(17ms): Asynchronous activity identified
```

We are seeing a lot of "reactor.core" calls that are unfamiliar to us as they are being executed internally by Mule, this fact makes it hard for us to understand what Mule is really doing.

Does somebody have an idea what is happening perhaps it could give us a clue what is going on between Mule and ActiveMQ? Perhaps better understanding all of this could help us find an answer to why this is responding so slowly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Reactor is a framework for building Java non-blocking applications used in the engine of Mule 4.x. The stack trace that you share doesn't point to any problems in Reactor or Mule. While reactor usually has longs stack traces, you can see the time spent in Reactor is non-measurable by AppDynamics. All the time seems to go into error handling by different classes, that have no relationship with Reactor. The time seems to be all spent inside JMS (`JMS(28030ms): acme.corp.error.topic`) and then error handling (`net.jodah.failsafe.Functions:lambda$promiseOfStage$8:193 (method time = 26148 ms`). You didn't share any other concrete details so that is a much as it is possible to analyze with the data provided. You also didn't provide details on the issue itself, only that there are "severely high response times". Examples of more details could be: What the applications do? How they interconnect? What connectors they use? How they use them? How are they configured? Exactly what operations are having timeouts, and what are those timeouts?

Last time I check AppDynamics doesn't know about Mule 4 internals so you must be prepared to do your own analysis of the data and not follow it blindly.

Analyzing this kind of issue could have many causes and you need to work holistically confirming or discarding all of them. To give you a very brief suggestion of items to perform the analysis:

1. Thread dump analysis: see if there are threads working on ActiveMQ or JMS connector classes. See if there are threads working on similar classes not related to ActiveMQ/JMS that maybe slowing down the rest.
2. Software analysis: what connectors versions and Mule patches are you using? Cumulative patches are critical in Mule 4 to prevent known issues. With connectors it is recommended to use the last version to prevent known issues.
3. Network analysis: perform network data traffic capture and analysis to see if there delays or communication issues
4. Configuration analysis: what time outs are configured? What resources are applied?
5. Workload analysis: are there peaks? Have the volumes changed? Have you previously performed tests at the same volumes?
6. Change analysis: has anything changed? New versions? Operating system patches?
7. ActiveMQ analysis: have you analyzed the ActiveMQ server in case the problem is there?